# Can the type of (a == b) be derived to be polymorphic?

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism

Since `(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool`, I'd expect

```
a == b :: Eq a => Bool
-- assuming a :: forall a. a
-- derived type
```

but (according to GHCi `:t`)

```
a == b :: Bool
```

Now of course, this requires `TypeApplications`, so it shouldn't be enabled by default, but is there a `LANGUAGE` option that enables this?

`NoMonomorphismRestriction` doesn't work.

EDIT: Since you may say, "well, GHC(i) already knows the type of `a` and `b` in any practical example", no, for example, you could have `(5 == 5) :: (Num a, Eq a) => Bool`.
EDIT: It seems `a :: forall a. a` isn't possible, so let's assume something like `x = 5 :: Num a => a`

EDIT: Explicitly declaring the type *works*, so the question is really "Can GHC infer this type to be polymorphic", so I'm looking for something like `DeriveAmbiguousTypes`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is all about the type of `(==)`:

```
(==) :: forall a. Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
```

`(==)` takes four arguments, *in order*:

1. A type, `a`, of kind `Type` (AKA `*`),
2. A dictionary of type `Eq a`,
3. A value of type `a`.
4. A value of type `a`.

As usual, partial application only works *in order*, and dictionary arguments cannot be passed explicitly. Furthermore, type arguments can only be introduced before they're used. So when you write `a == b`, this actually means

```
(==) @_ @{dict} a b
```

The type argument and dictionary argument are inferred, and you get a value of type `Bool`.

What you're after has a rather different type from `(==)`:

```
numLitEq
  :: (forall a. (Num a, Eq a) => a)
  -> (forall b. (Num b, Eq b) => b)
  -> forall c. (Num c, Eq c) => Bool
numLitEq a b = (==) @c a b
```

You can't write exactly this, though, because there's no way to get the `c` type variable into scope. The best you can do is

```
numLitEq
  :: forall c.
     (forall a. (Num a, Eq a) => a)
  -> (forall b. (Num b, Eq b) => b)
  -> (Num c, Eq c) => Bool
numLitEq a b = (==) @c a b
```

which isn't any better than just using `(==)`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this just works – in GHC-8.2 and 8.3 at least.

```
GHCi, version 8.2.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :set -XRank2Types -XUnicodeSyntax
Prelude> let x, y :: ∀ a . a; (x,y) = (undefined,undefined)
Prelude> :set -XAllowAmbiguousTypes 
Prelude> let p :: ∀ a . Eq a => Bool; p = x==y

Prelude> :set -XTypeApplications 

Prelude> p @Int
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at libraries/base/GHC/Err.hs:79:14 in base:GHC.Err
  undefined, called at <interactive>:3:36 in interactive:Ghci1

Prelude> p @(String -> Double)
<interactive>:11:1: error:
    • No instance for (Eq (String -> Double)) arising from a use of ‘p’
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    • In the expression: p @(String -> Double)
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = p @(String -> Double)
```

Comment: It doesn't, what version of GHCi are you using?

Comment: Hm, I'm a bit behind with my go-to compiler version again. Do you use a newer compiler and it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, I use 8.6.5, and GHC has several complaints. 1) Enable ScopedTypeVariables so you can use forall and write type signatures to let bindings 2) It doesn't work because "GHC doesn't support impredicative Polymorphism"

Comment: Yet `(x == y) :: Bool`

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you're just asking if the expression `3 == 5` can be made polymorphic in the type of `3` and `5`, the answer is yes.  The signature must be given explicitly with the help of some language extensions, but the following definition is polymorphic:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module ThreeFive where

eq35 :: forall a . (Num a, Eq a) => Bool
eq35 = (3 :: a) == 5
```

Alternatively, you could use `TypeApplications`:

```
eq35' :: forall a . (Num a, Eq a) => Bool
eq35' = (==) @a 3 5
```

Now, GHCi *reports* the type of `eq35` as `Bool`, but that's a lie, as you can see by adding the `+v` flag:

```
> :type eq35
eq35 :: Bool
> :type +v eq35
eq35 :: (Num a, Eq a) => Bool
```

or by proving it:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

-- Holistic number are all equal
newtype Holistic = Holistic Int deriving (Num)
instance Eq Holistic where
  _ == _ = True

main = do print (eq35 @Int)
          print (eq35 @Holistic)
```

and running this will print `False` and `True`.

I don't see any sort of combination of language extensions that would allow GHC to *automatically* infer a more general type for `3 == 5` than `True` in the absence of explicit type signatures.  Similarly, however polymorphic `x` and `y` might be, `x == y` will be either defaulted to a monomorphic type or rejected unless you use an explicit signature like the one above.